# Possible to set file_field to multiple files?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I have a file upload input with the following HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="assets" name="assets" multiple="multiple" webkitdirectory="webkitdirectory">
```

I am able to upload a single file like so:

```
single_file = "/Users/me/Downloads/Demo Folder/1428441/1.wav"
upload = @browser.file_field(:id => 'assets')
upload.set single_file
```

However, when I try to upload multiple files, by selecting the top-level directory (which works if I try doing this in my browser manually):

```
assets_folder = "/Users/me/Downloads/Demo Folder/1428441"
puts "Does dir exist? #{File.directory?(assets_folder)}" # true

upload = @browser.file_field(:id => 'assets')
upload.set assets_folder
```

It fails to upload at all. If I try creating a array containing the filepaths of 2 different files:

```
files = []
files.push("/Users/me/Downloads/Demo Folder/1428441/1.wav")
files.push("/Users/me/Downloads/Demo Folder/1428441/2.wav")
upload = @browser.file_field(:id => 'assets')
upload.set files
```

I see that this method only accepts a string as a parameter: `can't convert Array into String (TypeError)`

Is it at all possible to select multiple files via the `file_field`'s `set` method?

If not, what other workarounds could I try? I briefly looked at trying to inject JavaScript but apparently that's not possible either, according to "[How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)"

Answer (score 0):

Try by setting multiple filepaths, by seperating them with semicolons and see if that works(not tested), like this:

```
multiple_file = ("/Users/me/Downloads/Demo Folder/1428441/1.wav" ; "/Users/me/Downloads/Demo Folder/1428441/some_else.wav")
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Only the second file (2.wav) uploads when I try to do this.